Maximum value of $\Re(f(z))$
For $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $0<\Re(z)<1$ is a constant, consider  $$ f(z):= (z+2)\log(z+2)+(
1-z)\log(1-z)+3 z\log z-3(1+z)\log(1+z)$$ where $f(z)$ has branch cuts along the rays $[1,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0]$.

Question: I need to find the maximum value of $\Re(f(z))$ on $0<\Re(z)<1$

Let $z=c+iy$ and define $g(y):=\Re(f(c+iy))$ where $0<c<1$. We need to find $\max_{0<c<1}\Re(f(c+iy))$. So we have $$g(y)=\frac{f(c+iy)+f(c-iy)}{2} $$
On differentiation with respect to $y$ we obtain
$$g'(y)=\frac{1}{2}(if'(c+iy)-if'(c-iy)) $$
So we have $$g'(y)=-\left(\frac{f'(c+iy)-f'(c-iy)}{2i}\right) $$
Hence we obtain $$ g'(y)= -\Im(f'(c+iy))$$
For maxima or minima $$ g'(y)=-\Im(f'(c+iy))=0$$
Hence $$\Im(f'(z))=0$$
Now $$f'(z)=3\log z+\log(z+2)-\log(1-z)-3\log(1+z) $$
So we obtain $$\Im(f'(z))= \Im\left\{\log\left(\frac{z^3(z+2)}{(1-z)(1+z)^3} \right)\right\}=0$$
$$\Im(f'(z))=0$$
Here onwards I am stuck. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
Edit $1$: I found the following representation of $\Re(f(z))=\Re(f(c+iy))$ using Wolfram Alpha, see here which needs further simplification so as to find the maximum on $0<c<1$.
Edit $2$: Since we have
$$ \Im\left\{\log\left(\frac{z^3(z+2)}{(1-z)(1+z)^3} \right)\right\}=0$$
So we get $$\log\left(\frac{z^3(z+2)}{(1-z)(1+z)^3} \right)-\overline{\log\left(\frac{z^3(z+2)}{(1-z)(1+z)^3} \right)}  =0$$
We obtain
$$\log\left(\frac{z^3(z+2)}{(1-z)(1+z)^3} \right)-\log\left(\overline{\frac{z^3(z+2)}{(1-z)(1+z)^3}} \right)  =0$$
So we have
$$\log\left(\frac{z^3(z+2)}{(1-z)(1+z)^3} \right)=\log\left(\overline{\frac{z^3(z+2)}{(1-z)(1+z)^3}} \right)$$ On taking exponentials both side we get
$$\frac{z^3(z+2)}{(1-z)(1+z)^3}=\overline{ \frac{z^3(z+2)}{(1-z)(1+z)^3}}$$
So we get
$$\Im\left(\frac{z^3(z+2)}{(1-z)(1+z)^3}\right)=0$$
Wolfram Alpha gives some solution of above equation, see here
